# Find the Galois group of $x^5-6x+3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Find the Galois group of $ f(x) = x^5-6x+3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$. Then $G = Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ can be viewed as a group of permutations of the five roots of $f(x)$.

Now $x^5-6x+3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ for Eisenstein's Criterion with $p=3$. This means that $G$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_5$.

I'm not sure where to go now, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: discriminant${}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the Galois group $G$ of an irreducible polynomial $f\in \Bbb Q[X]$ of degree $p$ with $p>2$ prime having exactly $2$ non-real roots is generated by $(12\cdots p)$ and a transposition, which we may assume to be $(12)$, so that
$$
G\cong \langle (12\cdots p),(12)\rangle \cong S_p.
$$ 
Here this is satisfied for $p=5$. For further references, see the following duplicates:

[Galois group of a degree 5 irreducible polynomial with two complex roots.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153327/galois-group-of-a-degree-5-irreducible-polynomial-with-two-complex-roots?rq=1)

[Galois group of an irreducible polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602322/galois-group-of-an-irreducible-polynomial/677211)

[f irreducible polynomial with $p-2$ real roots $\Rightarrow$ $Gal(\mathbb{Q}_{f}/\mathbb{Q}) \cong S_{p}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3075225/f-irreducible-polynomial-with-p-2-real-roots-rightarrow-gal-mathbbq-f)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The other questions helped too.