# Galois Group of the Polynomial $x^5-6x+3$

Tags: galois-theory

Suppose $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $x^5-6x+3$. Determine the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$.

I can see that is has $3$ real roots. Also it is irreducible. Now how can I compute the Galois group?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153327/galois-group-of-a-degree-5-irreducible-polynomial-with-two-complex-roots?rq=1

Comment: for irreducible polynomials, the Galois group is a subgroup of $S_n$, the symmetric group on n elements. Furthermore the order of the Galois group is equal to the degree of the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of your polynomial. Now you have to use automorphism properties to determine the exact isomorphism type. If you are lucky, the Galois group is already determined by the number of elements.

Comment: I suppose you need the Galois group of the polynomial or more properly the Galois group of $K/\mathbb {Q} $ where $K$ is the splitting field. Note that $\mathbb {Q} (\alpha) $ is not the splitting field.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this from a higher point of view.

Proposition: Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $5$. Listing all (up to an isomorphism) the subgroups of $S_5$ which can be the Galois group of $f(x)$ one finds that for each group $G$ in the list we can give an example of an irreducible polynomial of degree $5$,
whose Galois group is $G$.

Solution:
$G$ must contains a $5$ cycle, because $5$ divides the order of $G$. Recall also that that if $G$ contains a transposition, then $G = S_5$. Assume first that $3$ divides $|G|$. Any group of order $15$ is cyclic, therefore $S_5$ does not contain a subgroup of order $15$. If $|G| = 30$, then $G$ is not a subgroup of $A_5$ (indeed it would be normal in $A_5$ but $A_5$ is simple).

But then $|G \cap A_5| = 15$, which is impossible as we have already shown. Therefore, if $3$ divides $|G|$, then $G = A_5$ or $S_5$.

Assume now that $3$ does not divide $|G|$. Note first, that $|G| \neq 40$, because if $|G| = 40$, then $G$ contains $D_4$, hence $G$ contains a transposition which is impossible. If $|G| = 5$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$. If $|G| = 10$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $D_5$, since $S_5$ does not contains a cyclic group of order $10$. Finally, $|G| = 20$, then $G$ contains is a semidirect product of a normal subgroup of order $5$ and a subgroup of order $4$. It is not difficult to see that a subgroup of order $4$ is cyclic and $G$ is isomorphic to $F r_5$.

Thus, the possible Galois groups are $\mathbb{Z}_5$, $D_5$, $F r_5$, $A_5$ or $S_5$.

In this example then, it is irreducible by Eisenstein criterion and has exactly two complex roots. Hence its Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $S_5$. Denote by $F$ a splitting field for $f (x)$. Let $G$ be any subgroup of $S_5$, then the Galois group of $f (x)$ over $F^G$ is $G$. Since $G$ acts transitively on the roots of $f (x)$, $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F^G$.